# Steam download breaks internet connection on Windows 7 (ISY N150)

Tags: windows, connection, steam

What happens: If I download anything via Steam, the internet connection breaks down in Windows 7. I'm using the ISY N150 WLAN stick.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question appears to be off topic fcor this site, I think you should move it perhaps to SuperUser.com where it might get answers

Answer (score 0):

How to solve it: The issue is driver related. The ISY N150 uses a Realtek RTL8192CU chipset. Go to the Realtek homepage, download the driver and replace your ISY driver. You will have to force Windows to use the RTL8192CU in the driver menu.